# php - parse html page

Tags: php, html, parsing

```
<div>divbox</div>
<p>para1</p>
<p>para2</p>
<p>para3</p>
<table class="table"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<p>para4</p>
<p>para5</p>
```

could someone please tell me how i can parse this html page to display ONLY para1, para2 and para3? and remove everything else.

condition:
i want to fetch **all the content** from the first **`<p>`** to the first **`<table class="table">`**.

(the first table will *always* have the class "table")

output:

```
<p>para1</p>
<p>para2</p>
<p>para3</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$d = new domdocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTML($file);

foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName("*") as $el) {
    if ($el->tagName == "p")
        echo $el->textContent, "\n";
    elseif ($el->tagName == "table")
        break;
}
```

This [gives](http://codepad.viper-7.com/imFsoM):

```
para1
para2
para3
```