# PHP Remove all paragraph tags inside header tags

Tags: php, regex

I've been dwelling on this for a while.

I have this string (there are more contents before and after the h2 tags):

```
...<h2 style='line-height: 44px;'><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></h2>...
```

What regex do I use to remove all the <p> and </p> tags inside those header tags?

I'm trying to do something like this, but the positive lookbehind one is not working:

```
// for the starting <p> tag
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=<h[1-6]{1}[^>]+>)\s*<p>/i', '', $str);
// for the ending </p> tag
$str = preg_replace('/<\/p>\s*(?=<\/h[1-6]{1}>\s*)/i', '', $str);
```

This does not take account paragraph tags deep inside the text within the <h2> tag also

**[Update]**

*This is derived from one of PeeHaa's suggested links*

```
// for the starting <p> tag
$str = preg_replace("#(<h[1-6].*?>)<p.*?>#", '$1', $str);
// for the ending </p> tag
$str = preg_replace("#<\/p>(<\/h[1-6]>)#", '$1', $str);
```

Comment: _Don't_ use regular expression, to deal with HTML. Use a parser, like DOM, for that.

Comment: Yes I know DOM is ideal but for this instance I have no choice to do this in PHP. Also, the paragraphs tags here are added automatically (WordPress) so they always appear like this and I need to remove them.

Comment: PHP knows DOM (and some other XML-parsers) too ;)

Comment: Oh hold on I misunderstood, I was initially thinking Javascript. :| But still, anyone for a regex suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try parse html with regexes, though having said that, since this is a subset of html and not a full document / nested layout, it is possible:

```
preg_replace('/(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?<p>(.*)?<\/p>\s?(<\/h\2>)/', "$1$3$4")
```

Test case here:

http://codepad.org/oA2rtNP9

Comment: Better. +1 for test case and for getting it into 1 line. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)

[Parse Website for URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461105/parse-website-for-urls)

[php - parse html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696937/php-parse-html-page)

And many many many others (I could have added 100+ more).

Basically the thing is:

**Don't try to parse HTML using regex.** HTML is not a regular language.

Use a HTML parser for this.

For example: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Yes I know this but for this instance I have no choice to do this in PHP. Also, the paragraphs tags here are added automatically (WordPress) so they always appear like this and I need to remove them.

Comment: @Jami: funny. that's what they all say :) Sure use regex and wait for the thing to bite you in the ass. :)

Comment: Subsets of html / non-nested code can be partially parsed with regexes. Though it's usually wrong, yes :p